# aapt.exe Error Finished with non zero exit value when adding android v7 support library

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I'm trying to import lib com.android.support:preference-v7:23.1.0 to my project.
However, when I add

```
compile ("com.android.support:preference-v7:23.1.0"){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
```

to my gradle build file. I receive the error:

```
Execution failed for task ':proxitag:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.E
xecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\nlthinh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build
-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1.
```

I tried clean and build the project, as well as updating the compileSdkVersion to 21 and buildToolsVersion 22.0.1.

Here is my full gradle build file:

```
import org.ajoberstar.grgit.*

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral();
    maven {
        url "http://repo.gradle.org/gradle/repo"
    }

    maven {
        url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
    }
    def androidHome = System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME")
    maven {
        url "$androidHome/extras/android/m2repository/"
    }



}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

configurations {
    compile
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile project (":preferencefragment")
    compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:3.1.3'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+"
    compile ("com.android.support:preference-v7:23.1.0"){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
    //exclude appcompat-v7 as it conflicted with the actionbarsherlock

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'], exclude: ['support-v4*.jar'])
}

android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    enforceUniquePackageName false
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

}

task copyJarDependencies(type: Copy) {
    description = 'Used for Eclipse. Copies all dependencies to the deps directory. If there are any AAR files it will extract the classes.jar and rename it the same as the AAR file but with a .jar on the end.'
    def libDir = new File(project.projectDir, '/deps')
    println libDir
    println 'Extracting dependencies from compile configuration'
    configurations.compile.filter {it.name.endsWith 'aar'}.each { File file -> moveAndRenameAar(file) }
    println 'Extracting dependencies from releaseCompile configuration'
    configurations.releaseCompile.filter {it.name.endsWith 'aar'}.each { File file -> moveAndRenameAar(file) }
    println 'Extracting dependencies from debugCompile configuration'
    configurations.debugCompile.filter {it.name.endsWith 'aar'}.each { File file -> moveAndRenameAar(file) }

}

void moveAndRenameAar(File file){
    println 'Added aar ' + file
    def baseFilename = file.name.lastIndexOf('.').with {it != -1 ? file.name[0..<it] : file.name}

    // directory excluding the classes.jar
    copy{
        from zipTree(file)
        exclude 'classes.jar'
        into 'deps/'+baseFilename
    }

    // Copies the classes.jar into the deps directory of the expoded AAR.
    // In Eclipse you can then import this exploded ar as an Android project
    // and then reference not only the classes but also the android resources :D
    copy{
        from zipTree(file)
        include 'classes.jar'
        into 'deps/' + baseFilename +'/libs'
        rename { String fileName ->
            fileName.replace('classes.jar', baseFilename + '.jar')
        }
    }
}

task copyNativeLibs(type: Copy) {
    from(new File(getProjectDir(), 'libs')) { include '**/*.so' }
    into new File(buildDir, 'libs')
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn copyNativeLibs }

clean.dependsOn 'cleanCopyNativeLibs'

tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniFolders = new HashSet<File>()
    pkgTask.jniFolders.add(new File(buildDir, 'libs'))
}
```

EDIT!: update the stacktrace log

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':proxita
g:processDebugResources'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex
ecuteActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex
ecute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExec
uter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.exec
ute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execut
e(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecu
ter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter
.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execut
e(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter
.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailur
e(AbstractTask.java:310)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorW
orker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorW
orker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorW
orker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(Defaul
tTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(Defau
ltTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTask
ExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecute
r.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExec
uter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecu
ter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildEx
ecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecute
r.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecute
r.java:55)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(Default
GradleLauncher.java:149)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradle
Launcher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLaun
cher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildCon
troller.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(Exe
cuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildA
ctionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.exe
cute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.exe
cute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.jav
a:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.
execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.
execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRunti
meValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRunti
meValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(
CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(
CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRep
ortingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRep
ortingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBoots
trap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.j
ava:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.ja
va:33)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.android.ide.common.proces
s.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
'C:\Users\nlthinh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finish
ed with non-zero exit value 1
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(Unch
eckedException.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:78)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskF
actory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:243)

        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskF
actory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskF
actory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:230)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskF
actory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex
ecuteAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex
ecuteActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 49 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.i
nternal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\nlthinh\AppData\Local\Android\
sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertN
ormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:42)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuild
er.java:854)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$processResources$1.call(Unkno
wn Source)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskActi
on(ProcessAndroidResources.groovy:159)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(In
crementalTask.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        ... 55 more
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users
\nlthinh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with n
on-zero exit value 1
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNo
rmalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertN
ormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:40)
        ... 60 more
```

**UPDATE**
The error output when running gradle with *assembleDebug --info* parameter

```
Successfully started process 'command 'C:\Users\nlthinh\AppData\Local\Android\sd
k\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe''
Unknown source file : ERROR: In <declare-styleable> Preference, unable to find a
ttribute layout

:proxitag:processDebugResources FAILED
:proxitag:processDebugResources (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.349 secs
```

Comment: Show your gradlebuild log.

Comment: I updated the stacktrace log as above

Comment: You have to compile with api 23. Also don't use different version of support libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all **`com.android.support:preference-v7` requires appcompat**.

You can check it in the pom file.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
  <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
  <version>23.1.1</version>
  <type>aar</type>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

**You can't use the appcompat and the sherlock together**. Remove the abs library.

Then, since you are using the v23 if com.android.support:preference-v7 you have to:

- **change the `compileSdk` to 23**
- **change the `buildTools` to 23**
- update the support libraries to 23, **don't use different versions of support libraries**

Somenthing like:

```
 compileSdkVersion 23
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

 compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1"
 compile ("com.android.support:preference-v7:23.1.1"){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
 }
```

Comment: Thank a lot. Removing sherlock lib fix the error. Now I'm working on migrating the code from sherlock to ActionBarCompat.